# Qt QGraphicsItem Objects Using GDI Handles

Tags: qt, gdi

Our product displays vector-based schematics, which are implemented using the QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene mechanism. On Windows, a drawing with 10,000 items hits the limit of 10,000 GDI handles per process. I've figured out how to increase the number of GDI handles available, but that's not really a solution, and with our application, it's impossible to increase the value enough to cover all possibilities since that would exceed the maximum Window limit.

I've been trying to figure out which Qt objects use up GDI handles (and there's a similar issue with USER objects), but I'm not having a lot of luck. The candidates that I've come up with so far are QBrush and QFont. I was able to eliminate a QBrush from each instance of my QGraphicsItem-derived object, but that didn't change the count of GDI handles used. Eliminating the QFont, even for simple testing is harder.

There are two of my own classes involved in my test display. For one of them, each instance includes a QBrush, QFont, QStaticText, several QRectF's, and a QColor. The other includes two QGraphicsRectItem's. Providing source code is problematic.

I've been searching the Qt source code for calls that create GDI handles and am not having much luck there either. Can anyone point me to a resource on this subject that's specific to Qt?

I'm using Qt 4.8.5, Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010.

Thank you,
Doug McGrath

Comment: Maybe create a small test app where you can test what exactly makes GDI handle count go up. It would also make a good basis for a new/rewritten question with code included. Your issue certainly does not sound normal.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to create a test app that I could post, but I've narrowed the problem to the use of QLineEdit within a QGraphicsProxyWidget for data entry purposes. Each of them appears to use two GDI handles and one USER object. We also used QComboBox for data entry in appropriate circumstances, and they exhibit similar problems. My suspicion is that this is a side-effect of the QGraphicsProxyWidget usage to make the widgets usable within a QGraphicsScene.

Comment: I just came across this question and I'm having a similar issue. I didn't realize QGraphicsProxyWidget would create USER objects, and I'm running up against the max # of windows per process. Do you remember having any luck figuring this out?

Comment: I've slept since then... :) But only what I mentioned in my comment with QLineEdit. My best recollection is that I just limited the number of them that I created. The reality of the situation is that it was highly contrived in terms of having 10,000 data entry fields on a single screen in our product. That particularly screen was a test screen to show data rather than do data entry, so I was able to work around it by eliminating some of the data entry widgets.

Comment: Wow, you actually saw that comment...thanks for responding! :-) Okay, well, I'm going to replace my proxy widgets with graphics widgets and hope it fixes my issue. I really just need to get my QML replacement finished and scrap all this old code. Thanks, again.

Comment: Good luck...I just happened to log in late that night by pure coincidence.